# how to display target of an org-mode link in the echo area or as tooltip?

Tags: org-mode, org-link, echo-area, tooltip

In org mode when I hover over a link, I get a tooltip that shows the target of the link. But I'd like to see the target when I just move point onto a link, either as a tooltip or in the echo area. For example, with:

```
* a headline
and a [[https://orgmode.org/][link to orgmode.org]]. And an internal link
[[id:20191211T100231.972516][to a headline in this file]].

* another headline with an ID property
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       20191211T100231.972516
  :END:
content
```

If point is somewhere in the "link to orgmode.org" text, I'd like to see  something like `LINK: https://orgmode.org` displayed in the echo area, or as a tooltip. Similarly for the internal link: it would be cool if the displayed text actually went and looked up the headline title and displayed `LINK: "another headline with an ID property"`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: org seems to be doing pretty much the right thing: it's setting the :help-echo text property, which hooks up to emacs' tooltips: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tooltips.html#Tooltips. I can do `M-x tooltip-mode` and get what I want...but for the mouse pointer, not the cursor: when I put the pointer over the text, I see the tooltip in the echo area. I want that to happen when the cursor/point is on the link. So how to detect /that/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr: do `M-x customize-variable` for the variable `help-at-pt-display-when-idle` and set its value to `t`. (Or "always", which is what the Customize buffer says.)

What was initially confusing here is that there's the mouse pointer, and also the cursor (which here on emacs.sx we call *point*). As mentioned above, `org-mode` by default sets the `:help-echo` property for links, which works with emacs' built-in *mouse* tooltip support. The idea of a "point tooltip" is separate, and, fortunately, is a solved problem: quoth [10.10 Help on Active Text and Tooltips](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Help-Echo.html):

> On terminals that don't support mouse-tracking, you can display the help text for active buffer text at point by typing `C-h .` (`display-local-help`). This shows the help text in the echo area. To display help text automatically whenever it is available at point, set the variable `help-at-pt-display-when-idle` to `t`.

Note that `help-at-pt-display-when-idle` doesn't immediately work if you enable it with `M-x set-variable`; from the variable's documentation:

> This variable only takes effect after a call to
>   `help-at-pt-set-timer`.  The help gets printed after Emacs has
>   been idle for `help-at-pt-timer-delay` seconds.  You can call
>   `help-at-pt-cancel-timer` to cancel the timer set by, and the
>   effect of, `help-at-pt-set-timer`.
>
> When this variable is set through Custom, `help-at-pt-set-timer`
>   is called automatically,